# Creating a booting stick with Ubuntu 18.04.4 for removing Windows 7 and Windows 10

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation, live-usb, rufus

I tried several times creating a booting stick according to found description.

- Downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.4 amd64 on Desktop and driver DVD from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop
- Tried manually to make the stick bootable through found description. Tried with Rufus-download but Rufus on my PC does not display the option to have Ubuntu  18.04.4 amd64 as Start. Rufus display several options as Start (translated from german): - "no start ability", - "Free DOS" and several other options.

When just copied Ubuntu on the stick, trying through Bios nothing could been found to start the PC through USB device.

No description which I tried works, it's frustrating!

Comment: Copying the ISO or its files won't do, since the DoK is still missing critical boot files - such files are created with tools like rufus as you already tried. What exact guide did you use?  Was it this official guide by [Canonical](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview)? Or was it this guide from [Ubuntu's documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - not all USB sticks are bootable. I never really checked why, but I have two from the same vendor where only one of them is bootable and second is not. So please try with other sticks, too to make sure you're not trying with a non-bootable one.

Second: make sure to choose options correctly. Rufus website has a pretty good image on this:
https://rufus.ie/pics/rufus_en.png
make sure ALL options are like this image, download 18.04 ISO and provide it to rufus.

this should work, just tried on my windows 10 laptop, works well and boots (yay) :)

Comment: Is it? I never stumbled upon a DoK that can't be made bootable.. You just need to format it and create one or more partitions. After adding the needed boot files and some kernel and initrd (any OS or even minimal) it should always work as long as the files compatible with your hardware.